# How to stop jQuery animations from overriding inline styles?

Tags: jquery, slidedown, inline-styles

My problem is a little complicated.

I have a navigation menu, complete with dropdowns that rely on the `slideDown()` animation for functionality. My dropdown has to have a `margin-top` due to the way that I style it, but I have to set the `margin-top` with jQuery after window load based on the user's font, zoom, etc. settings. To do this, I use `attr("style","margin-top: -22px !important")`. This makes my dropdown work exactly as it should. However... when I use `slideDown()`, jQuery removes my `!important`, which is crucial to the animation of the dropdown. If I don't use `!important`, `slideDown()` will animate both `margin-top` and `height`, which does not look good.

My question is: Is there any way to stop jQuery from overriding my inline style?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Sy9dC/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use **css({})** to change css propertie value of element:

```
$(".navigation-secondary-submenu").css('margin-top'," -10px");
```

or you can use :

```
$(".navigation-secondary-submenu").removeClass('old_class').addClass('new_class')
```

where **new_class** have your css properties .

```
.new_class{
    ******
    margin-top: -10px !important;
}
```

or this css property will be added dynamic:

```
$(docyment).ready(function(){
      $(".navigation-secondary-submenu").attr('style','margin-top:-22px !important');

     $("button").click(function() {
         $(".navigation-secondary-submenu").attr('style','margin-top:-10px !important');
      });
});
```

Comment: I need `margin-top` to be `!important`, which `$.css()` does not support. Otherwise, `slideDown()` will animate the margin, which is unintended.

Comment: Adding the styles through predefined CSS classes is a possibility. However, it's very inelegant because the calculated margin-top could vary widely from -35 to -5 depending on the user's zoom/font settings.